# Pass GET parameters in query-string

Tags: url, query-string

I need to do 2 things:

- Pass couple of parameters to querystring
- Redirect to URL given in one of parameters

One of the parameters is `redirect=URL_here`.
The problem is, that i must redirect to that page: `/about/me?look=1&sort=asc`
Then, my URL looks like:

```
/mypage/?letter=S&redirect=/about/me?look=1&sort=asc
```

I know that this is wrong (contains two "?").
The question is, how to make that query string correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL encode the query string values.

Answer (score 0):

change `=` sign with your own like `||` on your link. In your case change link like this
`/about/me?look||1&sort||asc`

Then later you will change `||` with `=`

Answer (score 0):

Use Url encode

Like this

```
<script>
var c= 'd e'
var query= '?a=b&c='+encodeURIComponent(c);
var uri= 'http://www.example.com/script?query='+encodeURIComponent(query);
window.location= uri;
</script>
```

and use

```
 decodeURIComponent()
```

to decode

Comment: There is no way to put JS anywhere. The only way I can do it is to prepare proper query-string - it's used in closed system, and code can't be changed.

Comment: then replace your ? and & with other special char like mypage/?letter=S&redirect=/about/me*look=1^sort=asc

Comment: What is the benefit of that? If I'll change look=1& to look=1^
How will it work then?